# Add new rows in datagrid flex 4?

Tags: datagrid, flex4

I need to insert some values of sliders, positions to datagrid in flex 4. Then i'll save those values in MySql.

All the values are overwriting on the first row of datagrid, how to insert new rows? I tried addItemAt() but did not work.

```
databaseData.addItem({distortion:"X  " + a, originalimage:"4 * 4", w2simage: "4 * " + a, brainimage: "4 *"+ a,
                transformw2s: " ",transformbrainimage:""});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the collection providing to the datagrid has no sort applied to it. Then you should be able to use addItem() and addItemAt() on the collection and new rows should appear at the end. If no rows appear at all it can be caused for some error preventing the collection to dispatch its collection changed event.
I hope this is of help to you.